# Query a byte property with nhibernate cause invalid cast error

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

Is there any problem with nhibernate 3.1.0.4000 where query a byte property:

```
byte code = 2;
Group g = Repository<Group>.FindOne(p => p.Code == code);
```

Exception text:

```
Cause 'Specified cast is not valid.'

[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
   NHibernate.Type.ByteType.Set(IDbCommand cmd, Object value, Int32 index) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Type\ByteType.cs:44
   NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, Object value, Int32 index) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Type\NullableType.cs:180
...

[GenericADOException: could not execute query
[ select group0_.LabourLawGroupId as LabourLa1_235_, group0_.Code as Code235_ from personnel.LabourLawGroup group0_ where group0_.Code=? ]
  Name:p1 - Value:4
[SQL: select group0_.LabourLawGroupId as LabourLa1_235_, group0_.Code as Code235_ from personnel.LabourLawGroup group0_ where group0_.Code=?]]
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:1703
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:1601
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:1591
   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Loader.QueryLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Loader\QueryLoader.cs:300
   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\QueryTranslatorImpl.cs:108
   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLQueryPlan.PerformList(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session, IList results) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\HQLQueryPlan.cs:78
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:645
   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters parameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\AbstractSessionImpl.cs:92
   NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionQueryImpl.List() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\ExpressionQueryImpl.cs:60
   NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery(NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression, IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhQuery) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\NhQueryProvider.cs:79
   NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\NhQueryProvider.cs:103
   System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +265
   Azarakhsh.Framework.Repository.NHibernateRepository`1.FindOne(Expression`1 expression) +223
   Azarakhsh.Framework.Repository.Repository`1.FindOne(Expression`1 expression) +100
```

Comment: Please post the exception detail/stack trace.

Answer (score 6):

I'm getting the same error with the same version of NHibernate using a Linq2Nhibernate query like this:

```
var details =
    (from d in repository.AllEntities
        where (d.OtherTable.Field == someCriteria && d.LineIndex == 1)
        select d).ToList();
```

In this case, `LineIndex` is mapped as a .NET `Byte` (not nullable).  The top of my stack trace looks like this:

```
NHibernate.Type.ByteType.Set(IDbCommand cmd, Object value, Int32 index) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Type\ByteType.cs: line 44
NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, Object value, Int32 index) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Type\NullableType.cs: line 180
NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, ISessionImplementor session) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Type\NullableType.cs: line 139
NHibernate.Engine.QueryParameters.BindParameters(IDbCommand command, Int32 start, ISessionImplementor session) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\QueryParameters.cs: line 630
...
```

Looking at the source, the `Set` method looks like this:

```
public override void Set(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
{
    ((IDataParameter) cmd.Parameters[index]).Value = (byte) value;
}
```

So it's trying to cast an object to a `byte` and getting an invalid cast.  Interestingly when I cast my literal `1` to a `byte`, I still get the same error.  It also happens if I use a `const byte`.  Therefore I think it's something higher up the stack that's taking the `byte` and doing something weird with it.

It's particularly interesting that it's doing a `NullSafeSet`, when the field is not nullable.  As an experiment, I changed my `LineIndex` property to an `int` and I didn't get the invalid cast exception.  This appears to be a bug in NHibernate.  I'll try to stick this on the NHibernate bug tracker.

**Edit**

Note that [this similar bug NH-2485](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2485) was closed as a non-issue.

Other similar/overlapping bug:

- [NH-2789](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2789) LINQ query on byte? simple property fails on MSSQL 2005 (tinyint)

I submitted this bug:

- [NH-2812](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2812) Performing a Linq query on a non-null byte property throws an InvalidCastException

**Edit**

Version 3.3.1 and up resolves this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `short` instead of `byte`

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue today with NHibernate 3.2.x. The bugs listed by Scott Whitlock were marked as [fixed in 3.3.x](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2812?focusedCommentId=23873&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-23873), and I can confirm that upgrading NHibernate resolved this issue.